# TypeError: $ (...).typeahead is not a function even including typehead.js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <script src="js/typeahead.js"></script>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.doctor').typeahead({
                name: 'doctor',
                remote: 'doctor.php?query=%QUERY'

            });

        })
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form>
   <input type="text" name="doctor" size="30" class="doctor"        placeholder="Please Enter City or ZIP code">
     </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

error TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function
i am also includeing typehead.js file

Comment: You forgot to include `jQuery` before `typeahead.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you **did not** include the `jQuery` library, this step is required because the `typeahead` library **requires `jQuery` to work**.

Here, try this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//netsh.pp.ua/upwork-demo/1/js/typeahead.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("input.doctor").typeahead({
          name: "doctor",
          remote: "doctor.php?query=%QUERY"
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="doctor" size="30" class="doctor" placeholder="Please Enter City or ZIP code" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that you are trying to use my website as a source of script. I mean this line:

```
<script src="//netsh.pp.ua/upwork-demo/1/js/typeahead.js"></script>
```

Please use Google to find CDN for this script or use your hosting as script storage.
Please use this link as src for script

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.js
```